# Taking a map from OpenLayers to OpenLayers-Cesium. Vector layer issue

Tags: openlayers, ol-cesium

I had made a map with an WMTS raster layer, and a few WFS vector layers (polygon) in OpenLayers, and am now trying to get the same to work in OL-Cesium.
It's working to the point that everything displays as expected as long as

```
ol3d.setEnabled
```

stays false, i.e. the map is rendered in 2D.
When I set this flag to true, the globe with the raster WMTS layer displays fine, but the vector layers don't show up.
The map:

```
        const map = new Map({
          target: 'map',
          layers: [
            layerPop,
            layerWest,
            layerEeu,
            layerBricsplus,
          ],
          view: new View({
            center: [0, 0],
            zoom: 2
          })
        });
```

where layerPop is the raster layer, the others, vector layers.
I wondered whether the z-order in 3D ends up different, i.e. whether the raster layer occludes the vector layers. But removing the raster layer gives just an empty globe, no vector layers.
Checking what happens in the console, the vector layers 'exist', no problem logging their properties, "visible" is true and so on.
Looking at the requests, in 2D, OpenLayers sends the WFS requests for the vector layers. But in 3D, the requests for the layers just don't happen (although the requests for the raster layer tiles do happen).
So this seems to be somewhat at the root of the problem. The 3D cesium globe has somehow decided that the vector layer data isn't needed. Presumably it has decided they shouldn't be rendered for some reason.
Also worth mentioning, no errors can be seen in the console.
I've been looking at the OL-Cesium examples of vector layers, for a clue, maybe something, some flag, needs to be set on vector layers in OL-Cesium, as opposed to OpenLayers, to make them visible, so far without success.

Also maybe worth mentioning, I've made a globe with the same layers in pure Cesium, which has no problems dealing with those WFS layers. But I think it's clear that it's not some issue of OL-Cesium dealing with that vector data, since the requests never happen in the first place...

Comment: The issue seems to have something to do with timing. I had hardcoded the map to enable ol3D, which meant that the OL 2D map didn't load before. When I replace this with the construct from the examples, main.js, where the map loads first in 2D and then you switch it to 3D with a button, NOW the vector layers are displaying. Not quite sure which conclusion to draw from this.

Comment: A problem with my current approach of loading the OL 2D map first and then switching to Cesium 3D with a button: I'm trying to control the polygon layer opacity with a slider, as in the example 'layer-group', by setting myLayer.setOpacity(fromSlider);
This works fine in 2D, but has no visible effect in 3D, but without logging any error. It's as if the layer which I'm altering is a layer in the 2D map, but not the Cesium map.